# "Passed" or "Past" - Referring to a time in past compared to now

Tags: comparison

How can I compare the current time to a time in past? Should I use past or passed? 
Given that the current time is 14:10, which of the following is more appropriate to use?

> 14:10 is **passed** the morning time.
>   14:10 is **past** the morning
>   time.
>
> 14:10 is **passed** 14:00.
>   14:10 is **past** 14:00.

or even:

> We are **past** 14:00
>   We are **passed** 14:00

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (1) **past** (plural pasts)
>
> The period of time that has already happened, in contrast to the present and the future.
>
> (2) **past** (adjective)
>
> past (comparative more past, superlative most past)
>
> Having already happened; in the past; finished.
>
> (postmodifier) Following expressions of time to indicate how long ago something happened; ago.

-

> **passed**
>
> Simple past tense and past participle of pass.

I think the best way to think about it, is that *passed* in the context of time is used wherever the word *elapsed* would be valid:

> Time has passed / time has elapsed
>
> Five minutes passed before either of us said anything.

*past* (except for *The Past* - meaning all time up until now) on the other hand is normally really a way of comparing two events, and generally means *further than* or *later than*.

> It's time for bed. It's past eight o'clock!
>
> The time now is half past three.

Comment: Matt, your answer is quite good, but would be more helpful if you specifically identified the parts of speech these words can take, as you've done with the adjective form.  Also, I can't come up with an example of the adjective "past" being used in either comparative or superlative form; can you?

Comment: @ShawnMooney: comparative: *Which of these two tins of beans is **more past** it's sell-by date?". Superlative: "Which TV show is **most past** it's prime?". They're both admittedly uncommon, but they're both real.

Comment: Great examples. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

*Past* means (among other things) "beyond in time; later than." In all your examples, you should use *past*.

> 14:10 is past the morning time.

> 14:10 is past 14:00.

> We are past 14:00.